# how to use a loop | apply | map to slice a data-frame for multiple variable values and create multiple statistics summary() in r

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to get multiple summary() outputs from a data-frame. I want to subset according to some characteristics multiple times. Then get the summary() of a certain variable for each slice and put all summary() outputs together in either a dataframe or a list.

Ideally i would like to get the name of each building_id i use to slice the data as a name for that row of summary().  So i thought of using a for loop.

The data are sufficiently large (about 20 m. lines) and i am using the train and building_metadata dataframes joined in one from the ashrae energy prediction from kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ashrae-energy-prediction/data)

I have created a tibble which holds the building ids i want subset by. I want to get the summary() of variable "energy_sqm" (which i have already created)  so i am trying to put this slicing in a for loop:

Warning 1: My building_id tibble has values like 50, 67, 778, 1099 etc. So one of problems i have is with the use of these numbers if i try to use them for some sort of indexing or naming my summary outputs. I think it tries to make row 50, 67 etc in the several differnt trials i did.

```
summaries_output <- tibble() # or list() `

for (id in building_id){

temp_stats <- joined %>% 
              filter(building_id == "id") %>% 
              pull(energy_sqm) %>% 
              summary() %>% 
              broom:tidy()
summaries_output <- bind_rows(summaries_output, temp_stats, .id = "id")
```

`

My problems:

a) whatever summaries_output i use to initialize i cant get it to retain anything inside the loop so i am guessing i am messing up the loop also.

b) Ideally i would like to have the building_id as an identifier of the summary() statistic

c) Could someone propose what is the good practice principle for these kind of loops in terms of using list, tible or whatever.

Details: The class() of summary() is `"summaryDefault" "table"` which i don't know anything about.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also use `tidyverse`.  After grouping by 'Species', `tidy` the `summary` output of 'Sepal.Length'.  Here, the `tidy` output is a `tibble/data.frame`.  In `dplyr` 1.0.0, we could use that without wrapping in a `list`, but it could also include a column name attribute with `$` because we have `out` and the column names from `tidy`.  To avoid that, we wrap in a `list` and then `unnest` the column created

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(out = list(tidy(summary(Sepal.Length)))) %>%
   unnest(c(out))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  Species    minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
#  <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 setosa         4.3  4.8     5    5.01   5.2     5.8
#2 versicolor     4.9  5.6     5.9  5.94   6.3     7  
#3 virginica      4.9  6.22    6.5  6.59   6.9     7.9
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I have been trying to figure out how to do it properly. I had consider the summarise solution but i couldn't figure out how to do it correctly. Can you please explain in little more detail why we are using a list inside the summarise call and why in the unnest call you use c(out) to un list the out list?

Comment: @thanosp Thanks.  I updated with some description.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be summarizing by group. Here's a way to do it with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) although I am unsure your exact expected output:

```r
library(broom)
library(data.table)
dt_iris = as.data.table(iris)
dt_iris[, tidy(summary(Sepal.Length)), by = Species]

#>       Species minimum    q1 median  mean  q3 maximum
#> 1:     setosa     4.3 4.800    5.0 5.006 5.2     5.8
#> 2: versicolor     4.9 5.600    5.9 5.936 6.3     7.0
#> 3:  virginica     4.9 6.225    6.5 6.588 6.9     7.9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a really nice answer and shows the simplicity and power of data.table, thank you so much! But since i started this workflow with the tidyverse style i will use that solution.